# VirtualBox: No IPv6 in Ubuntu guest (Win10 host)

Tags: networking, windows, virtualbox, ipv6, network-bridge

I'm using VirtualBox with Windows 10 as host and Ubuntu 16.04 as guest.
In general it's all working well but [a test for IPv6 connection](http://www.test-ipv6.com) tells me that I can't connect to IPv6 sites, leading to some minor issues when using apt-get or lftp. In the windows host the test is successful nevertheless.

Is there a possibility to use IPv6 in the Ubuntu guest, too? Or is there a limitation to IPv4 in VirtualBox/Ubuntu guest?

By the way, I'm using bridged network adapter, NAT doesn't work either.

Comment: any news on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an OLD question but for the record cause I faced such situation recently, VM is taking the IPv4 and IPv6 address from the virtualbox dhcp so you need to enable IPv6 in Virtualbox when using NAT network

first from the main virtualbox menu  file>preferences  or CTRL+G

[image]

Go to Network and add NAT network

[image]

double click the nat network and check the supports IPv6 option

[image]

open the settings for the Guest VM and configure the network to use the NAT network

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I almost forgot about this issue. Now I came back and was surprised to find the solution. Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 0):

Miredo is a package that can tunnel ipv6 through ipv4. From https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IPv6#Get_connected_with_Miredo, install it by running

```
sudo apt-get install miredo
```

I could successfully ping with ipv6 (ping6 ipv6.google.com) with a bridged network adapter and miredo.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Surely this works. Nevertheless I'd prefer to use the IPv6 connection yet existing and working on the Windows host. But I assume the problem falls back to VirtualBox rather than to Ubuntu. Btw: The host has only got a WLAN adapter I connect to "via wire" in VirtualBox settings.